# Creating a Firestore database for Firebase Storage files

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have an Android wallpaper app and it shows wallpapers that are stored in Firebase Storage. Currently, I am using Storage Reference in my Android project to access and show these files. Due to some limitation with this approach, I would like to create a Firestore Database for all these images which will have fields like file name, URL, uploaded date, etc. Is there any simple export mechanism to do this? Or do I have to create a custom project which will use Storage Reference to iterate through each and every image and write it to Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write code that does what you want.  There is no automated process for this.